# org-mobile-push from bash/crontab

Tags: android, bash, emacs, org-mode

On my former machine I would execute via crontab a script with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash
emacs --batch --load ~/.emacs --eval "(org-mobile-pull)" --eval "(org-mobile-push)"
```

On my new machine I use .emacs, init.el and custom.el from my old machine. But if I execute this script on my new machine the files I want to have pushed are not pushed. Obviously the variable org-mobile-files is not heeded, even though init.el and custom.el are loaded. Even worse: While a correct agendas.org file is created, I get an empty agenda on my android phone if I do a sync. If I execute org-mobile-push from inside a running emacs *and* having opened a org file everything works fine. How can I rewrite my script to push my files/agendas again from bash or crontab?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found a solution/workaround. I changed the script to open first an org file. My script now looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
emacs ~/Dropbox/path-to-org-files-directory/some-file.org --batch --load ~/.emacs --eval "(org-mobile-pull)" --eval "(org-mobile-push)"
```

This way my script works. The strange thing though: Before answering my question here I alread had tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
emacs ~/some-file.org --batch --load ~/.emacs --eval "(org-mobile-pull)" --eval "(org-mobile-push)"
```

This does not work ... As a matter of fact, opening some-file.org in my home directory in a running emacs session and then using org-mobile-push doesn't work either.